# Errors in add WCF service references?

Tags: c, wcf

My WCF project is OK, no errors, I try browse SVC file, it works well.
But when I add this WCF references, it throw errors :

```html
There was an error downloading 'http://MyIPAddress/BKKService/BService.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://MyIPAddress/BKKService/BService.svc'.
There was no endpoint listening at http://MyIPAddress/BKKService/BService.svc that could accept the message.
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

This is my web.config file

```html
<services>
      <service name="BKKService.BService">
        <endpoint address="BKKService" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="basicHttp" contract="BKKService.IBService"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://MyIPAddress/BKKService/BService.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an absolute address for each endpoint associated with the service or you can provide a base address for the ServiceHost of a service and then specify an address for each endpoint associated with this service that is defined relative to this base address.
When hosting with IIS, you do not manage the ServiceHost instance yourself. The base address is always the address specified in the .svc file for the service when hosting in IIS. So you must use relative endpoint addresses for IIS-hosted service endpoints.
So "http://MyIPAddress/BKKService/BService.svc" would not work, you need to use the .svc file address. If you use IIS express, the address for adding service reference should be the url when you browse the svc file. If you use IIS, it is the address specified for .svc file in IIS.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie in this field, please tell me clearly base on my code. please..